# When should we use public and when private?

Tags: c#, .net, coding-style

Should the Access Modifier be Public or Private when we are implementing method that is for now not using by other classes in our team solution?
I believe that "A public member says this member represents the key, documented functionality provided by this object.". We make private only "implementation details" methods and all methods that can be useful in future we should make public even for now there is no consumers of our methods in others classes. But my opponent says  that such methods should be private. How do you think?

Added:
Let's be more specific. For example there is a class SqlHelper.
In it there is useful functionality for operation with the SQL Server. 
In particular there is used connection to the SQL server. But not only in that class.

And for example I need to implement the public static HandleSqlExeption method(now only for class SqlHelper)  which will process SqlExeptions. But I want that in all classes where there is operations with SQL connection in exception handling will be used this method (instead of it is simple, for example:
    catch (Exception) { MsgBox {"SqlError"}; 
as somewhere happens now. So i consider that public access modifier will say to other colleagues that they can use this method. And private will hide that method. And i will need ti change code and rebuid assembly if some one will ask to use tsuch method. Why? There is only negatives.

Comment: Read this MSDN link it explains clearly [Access Modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: My rule of thumb: Everything should be `private` until you actually need it to be `public` (or `internal`, `protected`, etc)

Comment: @leppie: My rule of thumb is 100% the opposite. Everything that's part of the coherent interface the class provides and the logical functionality it offers should be public. (The funny thing is, our two rules would probably agree 98% of the time.)

Answer (score 11):

In general, you should code using the least possible permissive access modifier.

- If the method is not used outside the class, make it `private`.
- If the method needs to be used by inheriting types, make it `protected`.
- If the method will only be used within the assembly, make it `internal`.
- Only if the method is to be used outside the assembly should it be `public`.

This helps with [information hiding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding) and lets you change the implementation at will.

I have heard this described as protecting your privates.

---

In terms of API design, you should have a complete API, exposing all logical functionality as `public` - this is why you should use interfaces in .NET for API design, as all interface members must be `public`. In implementing classes, use the above rules of thumb for any members that are not part of the interface - unless they form a logical part of the interface, as far as its consumers are concerned.

---

So, if you have a `Read` method being used today, you should have a complementary `Write` method that has the *same* accessibility. That's a good design (symmetric and expected), but *how* you read or write should be hidden behind private methods, if the public ones use them.

Comment: But what if tomorrow someone other will need such method? I think it will be much easier to him to find that that he can use that public method that it is secure. Also it will be less chances that he will wright same functionality method for his needs.

Comment: Right, but if you have "next" and "previous" methods that are symmetric in purpose and implementation, you wouldn't decide to expose "previous" and not "next" just because you happened to have code that called "previous" and had written any code that called "next" yet. You want to present a coherent, complete interface.

Comment: @BransDs - YAGNI. If this is needed tomorrow, you change the access modifier tomorrow.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Sure. That's why I put that "In general". It's a good rule of thumb.

Comment: LOL that's absolutely true I agree with Oded totally

Comment: @Oded: I would argue it completely the other way around. The general rule should be that if it's logically part of the exposed public functionality of the class, it should be public, even if no code currently uses it. And if it's not logically part of the exposed public functionality of the code, you should try to modify other code *not* to use it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Of course it depends on the API details. But you wouldn't expose implementation details that are not relevant to the API, would you?

Comment: @Oded: No, but not because it's not called by clients, because it *shouldn't* be called by clients. The flipside of that is that even if it isn't called by clients, if it *should* be called by clients, it should be exposed. It's a mark of bad design if you have to keep changing a class just to add clients that still get the same logical functionality from the class.

Comment: @David - Sure. But that's why most APIs are declared in the form of interfaces in .NET - all members _must_ be public. It means that implements _must_ expose that API, but not anything else (unless needed/wanted).

Comment: @Oded: Right, that's my position -- present a complete and coherent interface that provides some logical functionality. Design a class to provide the functionality clients need, not the functions clients need. Then clients can get that functionality by calling the functions the class provides. "*If this is needed tomorrow, you change the access modifier tomorrow*" is crazy. If it's part of the logical functionality of the class, make it public today. If not, don't make it public tomorrow.

Comment: @David - requirements change. APIs change.

Comment: @Oded Read the original question. It's not about changing requirements or about changing APIs. It's about a function that should logically (looking at the function of the class and the API it exposes) be public but happens not to be called by any existing code. And that decision should be based on whether it's part of the logical functionality the class provides.

Comment: @David - I find that the points of view of someone designing an API that is to be widely distributed is very different from that of an _in house_ API where both the API and API clients are controlled by the same people, to be very different ones.

Comment: @Oded: Really, the only major difference is that for an in house API, you don't have to implement functionality until it's actually needed. But if you happen to already have it, if you'd expose it for a public API, you should probably expose it for an in house API.

Comment: @David - only if it is part of a coherent API (like you said - `Read`/`Write`).

Comment: @Oded: Read the original question. That's precisely what he's asking about -- functions that are part of the logical functionality but have no current callers.

Comment: I have added example. What about it. How do you has this SqlExeption handling method should be private or public?

Comment: @BransDs - Since it is part of a helper class, it should be `public`. If it were part of the implementation within some inheritance chain (like a base class) it might be more appropriate to make it `protected`.

Answer (score 1):

Use public and private depending on the nature of the method as name describes.

`public` when the method can be exposed to other objects and

`private` when the method should not be accessed by other objects.

If your object needs to be more secure, use `private` access specifier. You should also know about `protected` access specifier which is different in that, those methods can be accessed only by the objects that inherit them.

Answer (score 1):

if a class has some thing to expose to outside world then make it public else private. it depends on the functionality and purpose of class not the current or future requirement.

Answer (score 1):

This is a judgment call. Generally speaking, if it's logically a part of the interface the class is presenting to get the functionality it provides, it should be public even if it has no current users. That will reduce the chances that the class will need to be modified every time you want to use it for substantially the same things you're already using it for.

However, this has a cost. Each function you expose is a capability you are committing to provide. If, in the future, you decide to remove it from the public interface, you may break callers.

For example, consider a map class. Say you currently don't have any callers that need to know the number of items in the map, and your current implementation has a `size` variable you could easily return. You could add a `getSize` function that returns the size of the map. It's logically part of the function the map class exposes. So one can argue it should be public even if no current callers need to know the size.

However, it's entirely possible a future implementation might wish to get rid of the `size` variable. Perhaps the overhead of incrementing and decrementing the size is significant and implementation is changed to not need to know the size. If you exposed `getSize` function and it was called, you would either have to keep tracking the size even though you didn't need it or make the function very expensive, having to actually count the size.

Say lots of code needs to know if the table is empty and you provide an `isEmpty` function for this purpose. Experience shows that if you also provide a `getCount` function, people will do `getCount() == 0` instead of `isEmpty`. That may not make any difference today, but it may constrain your future implementation choices to keep `getCount` as cheap as `isEmpty`.

Where possible, I would strongly suggest making it public if you can easily imagine a non-broken user of the class that would benefit from having access to that functionality and it forms a logical part of the functionality the class provides. Otherwise, you can easily add it later anyway. So don't stress over it too much. It is largely a style issue mixed with trying to predict the future.

Comment: I have added example. What about it. How do you has this SqlExeption handling method should be private or public?

Comment: @BransDs: Is the fact that this class uses SQL and can throw SqlExceptions an internal implementation detail? Or is it specifically an SQL class? If the fact that it happens to use SQL to store things is an implementation detail, definitely this should be private. If it's an SQL class and everyone who uses it understands it can throw such exceptions (they just don't currently happen to care), then it should probably be public. (Though there's a bit of a code smell here. Why a handler? Why not pass the exception to the callers?)

Answer (score 0):

A basic principle of object oriented development; an instance of a class should only expose what needs to be accessed by it's clients. See [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) and search for "encapsulation".

Comment: Note that this includes future clients, not just current ones. It's not "what current clients just happen to do" but what functionality the class is designed to provide so that its interface is a complete, coherent logical unit.